# Using mailto (incl. subject) link works in PDFs using Adobe Reader but not in Preview

Tags: macos, pdf, adobe, preview, mailto

I have added a hyperlink (mailto:someone@domain.com?subject=free beer) in a PDF I created using Adobe Acrobat Pro.

It works fine in Adobe Reader and opens up the mail client email address and subject in place.

But it doesn't do anything in Preview (the Mac application). 
The link doesn't open the mail client at all.

Can anyone suggest a work around?

Comment: Work around it by recommending to not use Apple's Preview. It is a substandard viewer, without support for lots and lots of PDF functionality. Adobe Reader is free.

Comment: Yes but the mailto link would trigger Preview if that's how the user has set up their machine no?